# put data in List thenn insert it its values into database

Tags: java, jdbc

I have to store questions in session afterward in List then insert them all into database by one click

my servlet

```
Question question = new Question(title, content, idExam);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("question", question);
        int quizKey = ExamDAO.add_question(question);
        ArrayList<Question> ques = new ArrayList<Question>();
        ques.add(question);
```

my dao

```
cnx = Connect.getConnection();
        String req = "insert into question(title, content, id_examen) values(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        st.setString(1, question.getTitre());
        st.setString(2, question.getContenu());
        st.setInt(3, question.getIdExamen());
        st.executeBatch();

        ResultSet rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();

        if (rs.next()) {


quizKey = rs.getInt(1);
            }
```

how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `st.executeUpdate()`. This is usually used for manipulating statements like `DELETE`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. The method will return either the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or 0 for statements that return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List<Question>` and you wish to insert all in one go then you have to utilize what is called as - batching or batch update. Refer [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html) for more details

You will be iterating your list of questions and setting parameters for each question then adding that statement to batch (by using st.addBatch()) &  then finally call - `st.executeBatch()`.

In your code sample, you are executing a batch but there is only one prepared statement in that batch. You need as many prepared statements as number of questions in the list.

```
    String req = "insert into question(title, content, id_examen) values(?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement st = cnx.prepareStatement(req, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    for(Question question : ques){
     st.setString(1, question.getTitre());
        st.setString(2, question.getContenu());
        st.setInt(3, question.getIdExamen());
       st.addBatch();
    }
st.executeBatch();
```

With this approach, you might have issues in collecting generated keys as illustrated in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065894/jdbc-preparedstatement-batch-update-and-generated-keys)  so if you really need those ids , you will have to turn off auto commit, execute updates in loop without batching, collected generated ids in a map or list for each insert statement and then finally commit your connection in the end.

Comment: in fact I want to put List of Question in a session, then to insert them all in database by one click. the query is is already done what about the List of question in servlet. how to do it ??

Comment: make your `Question` class serializable & then put `ques` in session. `ArrayList` is already serializable.